# how to add array of string to jsonObject?

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonobjectrequest

In this method, I have an array of strings i.e barchartLabels. I want to add this array to jsonObject:

Expected output is :

> { "data" : " [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July" ] " }

```
public String array() {
    JsonArray roleArray = new JsonArray();
    String barChartLabels[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"};
    Gson listG = new Gson();
    JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
    String list2 = listG.toJson(barChartLabels);
    jsonObj.addProperty("data", list2);
    roleArray.add(jsonObj);    
    return  jsonObj.toString(); 
}
```

In the above method I'm using Gson object to convert barchartLabels to string then using jsonObject adding it. But I'm getting the output as shown below. Is there any other way to do the above mentioned?

> { "data" : " [ \"January\", \"February\", \"March\", \"April\", \"May\", \"June\", \"July\" ] " }

Comment: It is the standard json format to escapse `"` so don't worry

Comment: This is webservice which is mentioned above. In the UI after getting response i'm retriveing this array from json and assigning it to array in UI ...which is creating problem ...

Comment: This is not a problem, all that is happening is that your `" "` are being escaped. As @Pavneet_Singh has mentioned, this is completely standard.

Comment: @SabnekarRajnikant please check my updated answer

Answer (score 4):

data is a `String`, not a `String[]`, so all the quotes are escaped. If you want a `String[]` just

```
    JsonArray data = new JsonArray();
    Stream.of(barChartLabels)
         .forEach(data::add);
    jsonObj.add("data", data);
```

listG.toJson is converting it to a JSON String, so when you add that, it's a String. Just skip that step and add it directly

Comment: method addproperty(string,string) in the jsonObject is not applicable for arguements(string,string[])

Comment: You could make this simpler by skipping the array and just  starting with a Stream.of("foo", "bar", "etc...")

Comment: method add(string,JsonElement) in the jsonObject is not applicable for arguements(string,string[])

Comment: @SabnekarRajnikant You commented after I updated the answer. Please look at the edit

Comment: Sorry this is taking so long, I use POJOs and Jackson, so had to learn the Gson stuff

Comment: Maybe suggest a `JsonArray` collector? It would be "more functional", I think. ;)

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Since JsonArray doesn't implement List or Collection for that matter, it's not really worth it for this answer IMO